# How to get a variable?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to insert a variable ttl into this conclusion: 'rotate ('".c1", 150, 100, "blue", 60, "30 628", -90);" instead of the number 628

after I insert the variable into the generation, the code stops working

I inserted it that way.

```
1) rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60, "30 ttl", -90);
2) rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60, "30 `${ttl}`", -90);
3) rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60,  `30  ${ttl}`, -90);
```

after that, the code didn't work

on the way out after the code works should get a segment that I'll show how to svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="300" 
     height="300" 
     viewBox="0 0 300 300" >
  <circle 
          fill="none" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="30" 
          cx="150" 
          cy="150" 
          r="100"
          stroke-dasharray="30 628"/>
</svg>
```

and that's the result I expect to get.

how can you fix a situation that would put a variable in function?

```js
let obj = document.querySelector("circle");
let ttl = Math.round(obj.getTotalLength());

function rotate(obj, cx, cy, r, stroke, w, da, rad) {
  let item = document.querySelector(obj);

  this.cx = item.setAttribute("cx", cx);
  this.cy = item.setAttribute("cy", cy);
  this.r = item.setAttribute("r", r);
  this.stroke = item.setAttribute("stroke", stroke);
  this.w = item.setAttribute("stroke-width", w);
  this.da = item.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", da);
  this.rad = item.style.transform = `rotate(${rad}deg)`;
}

rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60, "30 628", -90);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

circle {
  tranform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <circle class="c1" />
</svg>
```

how to insert a variable inside the finished function, how to replace the 628 on the variable ttl?

Comment: @AdrianLynch  doesn't want to work https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rNVrRXJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3rd version (using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) should work. If it doesn't, you should check that you are using a browser that supports them (no versions of Internet Explorer do), or that the computation of `ttl` yields the result you expect. If your browser doesn't support template literals, you can use

```
'30  ' + ttl
```

in its place.

```js
let ttl = 628;
console.log(`30  ${ttl}`);
console.log('30  ' + ttl);
```

Your code works fine in Firefox 74.0:

```js
let obj = document.querySelector("circle");
let ttl = Math.round(obj.getTotalLength());

function rotate(obj, cx, cy, r, stroke, w, da, rad) {
  let item = document.querySelector(obj);

  this.cx = item.setAttribute("cx", cx);
  this.cy = item.setAttribute("cy", cy);
  this.r = item.setAttribute("r", r);
  this.stroke = item.setAttribute("stroke", stroke);
  this.w = item.setAttribute("stroke-width", w);
  this.da = item.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", da);
  this.rad = item.style.transform = `rotate(${rad}deg)`;
}

rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60, `30 $ttl`, -90);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

circle {
  tranform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >
  <circle class="c1" />
</svg>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="300" 
     height="300" 
     viewBox="0 0 300 300" >
  <circle 
          fill="none" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="30" 
          cx="150" 
          cy="150" 
          r="100"
          stroke-dasharray="30 628"/>
</svg>
```

Or this should work in IE or earlier versions of Firefox etc.

```js
let obj = document.querySelector("circle");
let ttl = Math.round(obj.getTotalLength());

function rotate(obj, cx, cy, r, stroke, w, da, rad) {
  let item = document.querySelector(obj);

  this.cx = item.setAttribute("cx", cx);
  this.cy = item.setAttribute("cy", cy);
  this.r = item.setAttribute("r", r);
  this.stroke = item.setAttribute("stroke", stroke);
  this.w = item.setAttribute("stroke-width", w);
  this.da = item.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", da);
  this.rad = item.style.transform = `rotate(${rad}deg)`;
}

rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60, '30 ' + ttl, -90);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

circle {
  tranform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >
  <circle class="c1" />
</svg>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="300" 
     height="300" 
     viewBox="0 0 300 300" >
  <circle 
          fill="none" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="30" 
          cx="150" 
          cy="150" 
          r="100"
          stroke-dasharray="30 628"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: that's how it should turn out, like a red segment https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rNVrRXJ

Comment: @MaximLensky see my edit. I demonstrate template literals and string append versions. Both work fine in my browser but perhaps only the second will work for you?

Answer (score 1):

From you choice:

```
1. rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60, "30 ttl", -90);
2. rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60, "30 `${ttl}`", -90);
3. rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60, `30 ${ttl}`, -90);
```

3 is correct.

The issue is the calculation of `ttl`.

1 is just a string: `"30 ttl"`

2 is still just a string as the inner backticks aren't treated as a [template string/literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): "30 `${ttl}`"

To debug the issue you could have console logged the arguments passed into `rotate()`, more specifically, the `da` argument:

```
function rotate(obj, cx, cy, r, stroke, w, da, rad) {

  console.log("da:", da);

  let item = document.querySelector(obj);

  this.cx = item.setAttribute("cx", cx);
  this.cy = item.setAttribute("cy", cy);
  this.r = item.setAttribute("r", r);
  this.stroke = item.setAttribute("stroke", stroke);
  this.w = item.setAttribute("stroke-width", w);
  this.da = item.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", da);
  this.rad = item.style.transform = `rotate(${rad}deg)`;
}

var ttl = 100;

rotate(".c1", 150, 150, 100, "blue", 60, `30 ${ttl}`, -90);
```

Comment: @MaximLensky - Your sample code is missing the backticks.

Comment: that's how it should turn out, like a red segment https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rNVrRXJ

Comment: @MaximLensky - So you're now calling the rotate function correctly. That's what you wanted, right?

Comment: @MaximLensky - Read through mine or Nick's answers, ensure you're calling it like your 3rd option.